# I need to get vertical and horizontal scroll view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have a vertical scrollable list view(red arrow) and also i need horizontal listview (black arrow). But only dynamic the green box rows

[image]

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try this widget, you will get the idea

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("widget.title"),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 122; i++)
                    Card(
                      child: Text("let item upto Tags $i"),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text("item $index"),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [multiple-scrollbars](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_scrollbar#multiple-scrollbars) from [adaptive_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_scrollbar#multiple-scrollbars) package or [cross_scroll](https://pub.dev/packages/cross_scroll) package:

Answer (score 0):

Check interactive viewer. It will also allow you to zoom the ui along with scrolls

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 1.6,
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.orange, Colors.red],
              stops: <double>[0.0, 1.0],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```